# Cannot find solution to a randomly generated equation

Tags: python, random

im fairly new to python. trying to create a math quiz game as an assignment. i tried saving random int to a variable but that would return same value. i switched to creating a function, now im able to print a random equation but i cant know what i printed so i cant solve it to compare user answer.

This is my current code

```
import random

score = 0
symbol = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
def num():
    print(int(random.randint(1, 25)), end = '')
def sym():
    print(random.choice(symbol), end = '')
def eq():
    (num(), sym(), num())
eq()
def sol():
    #???
```

edit: using return value now, dont know what the error is

```
import random

score = 0
symbol = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
def num():
    print(int(random.randint(1, 25)), end = '')
    return(random.randint)
def sym():
    print(random.choice(symbol), end = '')
def eq():
    ques = (num(), sym(), num())
    return ques
equation = eq()
print(equation)
```

Comment: Use more `return` instead of `print` to collect the data in one place and then print it and calculate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an aproximation could be something like this :

```
import random

score = 0
symbol = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']

def equ():
    number1=str(int(random.randint(1, 25)))
    finalsymbol=str(random.choice(symbol))
    number2=str(int(random.randint(1, 25)))
    equation = str(number1+ " " + finalsymbol + " " + number2 + " = ")
    print(equation)

equ()
```

Answer (score 0):

That will work for you

```
import random

score = 0
symbol = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
def num():
    return int(random.randint(1, 25))
def sym(): 
    return random.choice(symbol)
def eq():
    x=sym()
    x1=num()
    x2=num()
    out=''
    if x=='+' :
     ques=x1+x2
     out=str(x1)+x+str(x2)+'='+str(ques)
     
    if x=='-':
     ques=x1-x2
     out=str(x1)+x+str(x2)+'='+str(ques)
    
    if x=='*' :
     ques=x1*x2
     out=str(x1)+x+str(x2)+'='+str(ques)
   
    if x=='/' :
     ques=x1/x2
     out=str(x1)+x+str(x2)+'='+str(ques)
     
    if x=='^' :
     ques=x1^x2
     out=str(x1)+x+str(x2)+'='+str(ques)
    
    
    return out
equation = eq()
print(equation)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... i switched to creating a function, now im able to print a random equation but i cant know what i printed so i cant solve it to compare user answer. ..."*

I believe *in-line* would work better in this situation.

```py
import random as r
e = str(r.randint(1, 25)) + \
    str(r.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '^'])) + \
    str(r.randint(1, 25))
print(e + ' = ' + str(eval(e)))
```

Output

```
7/3 = 2.3333333333333335
```

If you're looking to save the generated values, use the following.

```py
a = r.randint(1, 25)
b = r.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '^'])
c = r.randint(1, 25)
e = f'{a} {b} {c}'
print(f'{e} = {eval(e)}')
```

Output

```
15 * 24 = 360
```

---

Edit

Here is the *Python* tutorial on *while statements*.
*[Compound statements — Python 3.11.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)*.

```py
import random as r
exit = False
while not exit:
    e = str(r.randint(1, 25)) + \
        str(r.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '^'])) + \
        str(r.randint(1, 25))
    print(e + ' = ' + str(eval(e)))
    exit = input(r'again? y/n ').lower() != 'y'
```

Output

```
13+2 = 15
again? y/n y
3^16 = 19
again? y/n y
17*16 = 272
again? y/n n
```

Comment: thanks, how can i apply a while loop to this?